# Update SQL database to Wordpress date format

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a custom SQL database (`database`) and table (`portfolio`) with columns arranged as follows:

Col 1:`id`

Col 2:`year`

Col 3: `month`

Col 4: `day`

Col 5: `title`

etc.

I want to concatenate columns 2 to 4 in one single column (`date`) using Wordpress posts date format (ie. `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`). All times can have `00:00:00` value.

This is my query:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(`year`,"-", `month`,"-",`day`," 00:00:00") FROM `portfolio`
```

How can I insert result into a new column named `date`?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: so the portfolio table doesn't have a column named `id`. You can see all available columns with `SELECT * FROM portfolio` (or with phpMyAdmin or similar management tools).

Comment: however, it does have an id column. https://imgur.com/a/q5gxWPx

Comment: Are you certain you are in the same database in your server (between your phpmyadmin screenshot and whatever this sql is connecting to). It's unequivocally complaining about there not being a column named `id` in your `portfolio` table.

Comment: The `id` column is missing! - see the following demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=691c728a2ef6f01fdadcce36a766ec0b

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE portfolio;`  Edit your question with the result.Make sure you are in the right database when running your SELECT...

Comment: No more error, just need to insert the result into one new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to create a new column with the `DATE` or `DATETIME` value:

```
ALTER TABLE `portfolio` ADD COLUMN `column_name` DATE NULL
```

With the following `UPDATE` you can insert the date values to the new column:

```
-- month and day are integer values (1, 2, 3)
UPDATE `portfolio` SET `column_name` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `year`, `month`, `day`), '%Y-%c-%e')

-- month and day are string values (01, 02, 03)
UPDATE `portfolio` SET `column_name` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', `year`, `month`, `day`), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

> [**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd191c1833317891762dd28770600ede)